# Question on how SFINAE is achieved using this code segment

Tags: c++, logic, implementation, sfinae

With reference to

[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

the question relates to the following code segment:

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no [2];
    template<typename C> static yes& test(int C::*); // selected if C is a class type
    template<typename C> static no&  test(...);      // selected otherwise
  public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

In the above class template definition, the `public` definition for `is_class<T>::value` instantiates the nested static template function `test` using the parameter `T` used in the instantiation of the class template `is_class`.

If the above interpretation is correct, I have the following questions:

1. How does one interpret the overloaded versions of the the nested static template function `test`?

How does SFINAE work using the above overloads to populate the public boolean variable `value` of template class `is_class<T>` for a given `T`, with true or false as applicable, based on `sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)`? I am not sure I understand how passing what appears to be a random integer value `0` in the instantiation of `test<T>` should either choose or eliminate either overload? Can someone provide an explanation with an example?

2. The logic of using two nested types of `yes[1]` and `no [2]`, both of which have been typedef'd to `char` is also not clear to me. Assuming that `yes[1]` is a type alias for a char array with size 1, and `no[2]` a type alias for a char array with size 2, how does this logic integrate into the overload selection/elimination using SFINAE?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clear some misunderstandings:

1. `yes[1]` is not a type. `yes` is a type, and it is an alias for `char [1]`.
2. `no[2]` is not a type. `no` is a type, and it is an alias for `char [2]`.

When it comes to overload resolution, `test(...)` is given lower priority if `T` is a `class`. Hence, the call `test<T>(0)` will resolve to the first overload, whose return type is `yes&`. Consequently,

`sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)` evaluates to
`sizeof(yes) == sizeof(yes)`, which evaluates to `true`.

If `T` is not a class, there is no `int T::*`. That's the SFINAE part. For that case, `test(...)` is chosen as the overload, whose return type is `no&`. Hence,

`sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)` evaluates to
`sizeof(no) == sizeof(yes)`, which evaluates to `false`.